# Hardware prerequisites for Tridion 2011 SP1

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

We are starting with upgrade from Tridion 5.3 to Tridion 2011 SP1.

When we go through prerequisite document we got all the software prerequisites there like Operating system, IIS, .net, java etc.

Where we can find hardware prerequisites for Content Manager Server as well as Content Delivery server ? Does Tridion recommend them anywhere ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tridion doesn't come with hardware prerequisites as those depend on too many variables.

If wanted you can contract a (SDL or partner) consultant to do an upgrade scan and estimate how your current hardware setup would be translated to a new platform.

Answer (score 2):

Or at least contact customer support, there is a whitepaper about SDL Tridion hardware sizing recommendations.